# What causes this odd Uncaught Reference error when adding product to cart Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, error, addtocart, jquery

Since today, adding products to cart has stopped working on our site with the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery172016024149750625072_1490834796904 is not defined
    at ajaxcartsuper/ajaxcart/add/uenc/ahr0cdovl2luzhvjdg9ylmnvbs9jdhrmmdiwmwhjzi0…4&options%5b295%5d=&qty=0&product=18244&related_product=&_=1490834978446:1
```

What could be causing this error? I checked everything. Nothing new has been added other than mysql settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ask your extension vendor?

Comment: Well, it is a multistore setup. Both stores with different Themes. Adding to cart from category works fine, it is on single product page that is not working. On the second site, there is no error. After clicking "add to cart", user is taken to cart page which says "you have no items in cart". So no, I haven't contacted vendor since the cart is not working on either site but it did until yesterday.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError` means an error when a non-existent variable is referenced. The var in question here is `jquery172016024149750625072_1490834796904`. As this didn't happen before, a possibility is your site was hacked into. You need to check your code in master branch if you use git against the code in the server(s). If you do not have version control system, scan your server for possible intrusions, or check if any files were added recently around the time when you noticed the error.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737270/ajax-cart-super-didnt-work-on-chrome, I can see that `jquery172016024149750625072_1490834796904` is a callback function which doesn't exist. Check for similar function in your browser developer mode or you can call your vendor for solution.